# Showing that $E(X)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(X\geq n)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I have the following question in my textbook and i'm not quite sure how to answer it.

Question: Let $\{\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\}$ be a probability space, and let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ be an integrable random variable that takes values in $\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $$E(X)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(X\geq n)$$

I know that after some $n$, $P(X\geq n)$ should be $0$, but i'm not sure how to show this and is this even a correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $f(n) = P(X=n)$.Observe that $P(X \ge n ) = f(n) + f(n+1) + f(n+2) + \ldots$.

Then $E(X) = 1f(1) + 2f(2) +3f(3) + \ldots$. So
$$E(X) = (f(1) + f(2) +f(3) + \ldots) + (f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + \ldots) + (f(3) + f(4) + \ldots) + 
\ldots $$

Formalise this idea.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
E(X)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(X=n)\\
&=P(X=1) + 2P(X=2)+3P(X=3)+\dots\\
&=\left(P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+\dots\right)+(P(X=2)+P(X=3)+\dots)+(P(X=3)+\dots)+\dots\\
&=P(X\geq 1) + P(X\geq2)+P(X\geq3)+\dots\\
 &=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(X\geq n)\\
\end{align*}$$