# Showing that $E(X)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(Y\geq n)P(Z\geq n)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230848/showing-that-ex-sum-infty-n-1px-geq-n).

Let $Y,Z:\Omega\to \mathbb{N}$ be integrable random variables that take values in $\mathbb{N}$. Further assume that the random variables $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Define $X=\min\{Y,Z\}$. Prove that $$E(X)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(Y\geq n)P(Z\geq n)$$

I am not completely sure how this is supposed to be proved.

I know that by definition an integrable random variable (with sample space $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,...\}$) if and only if $$E(X)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}X(\omega_n)P(\omega_n)$$

So I'm not completely sure how to use this deinition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know that $E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\geq n)$ and $X=\min\{Y,Z\}$ then $$\begin{align*}
E(X) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\geq n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\min\{Y,Z\}\geq n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y\geq n\text{ and } Z\geq n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y\geq n)P(Z\geq n)\\
\end{align*}$$

The last equality in due to independance of $Y$ and $Z$.